# sudo geany throws fatal error

Tags: sudo, text-editor, geany

I really like the Geany text editor, and would like to use it instead of gedit for all text editing.  However, every time I try to launch Geany from the terminal using `sudo geany file.conf`, I get this error:

> (geany:10203): Geany-WARNING **: Geany tried to access the Unix Domain socket of another instance running as another user.
>
> This is a fatal error and Geany will now quit.

I am the only user logged in to the machine.  There are no instances of Geany already running when I type that command into the terminal.  Geany has no trouble launching from the command line if I don't use a `sudo`.  I also don't have any trouble running Gedit with elevated privileges; the command `sudo gedit file.conf` functions flawlessly.

What is going on here?  How can I fix this so that I can edit text files in Geany with elevated privileges?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: I'm using sudo when I want to edit a file that needs elevated privileges; as just one example, `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Comment: What about gksudo?

Comment: Right then, as the link above says, use gksudo.

Comment: thanks, `gksudo` does the trick.  why does `sudo gedit` work-- shouldn't gedit also need the `gksudo`?

Comment: It should... Gedit is assuming the user knows to do it right (not use `sudo`. It is a bad idea on GUI apps...

Comment: `sudo geany <filename>` works fine for me, on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `sudo geany <filename>` has been working for more than a year. Today I got this error message for the first time.

Comment: Why does this error happen, and what can be done to prevent it?

Comment: Why the HELL an editor must CARE about how you use as sudo or not ???

Answer (score 21):

Try deleting this file:

```
sudo -H rm ~/.config/geany/geany_socket_*
```

if you want you can move them to some folder temporarily.

Comment: `NOTE: sudo geany <filename> works fine on my Ubuntu 14.04` Works & a good idea aren't synonymous

Comment: @doug i said that because some people in comment above are advising to use gksudo which may not solve the problem

Comment: If you do want to use `sudo`, at least use `sudo -H`.

Comment: I had same issue manually I did delete the socket file in .cofig/geany and worked for me too thanks :)

Comment: Unbelieveable! I would never solve this on my own!

Comment: @edward-torvalds  'box' seems to be your specific machine name (as in `uname -n`). One better types `sudo -H rm ~/.config/geany/geany_socket_` and then press **tab** to see, what comes for autocomple (i.e. __<my-machine>__0)